# update number sequence in AX

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, dynamics-ax-2012-r2

I had to import data in `hcmposition` table.
however, the `positionid` look like `000001` and I have used X++ to insert data into hcmpostion from an external table.

after the data is inserted, I tried to create a position form AX position form and I got the following error

```
Cannot create a record in Positions (HcmPosition). Position: 000001.The record already exists
```

in order to fix the issue I have tried to update the `SYSTEMSEQUENCES` table by updating the `nexval` field to be equal the maximum recid +1  available in `hcmpositon`.

however, I am still getting the same error.

Comment: Do you have the code you're using? This is a pretty straight forward error that you're violating the unique index.

Comment: the position 00001 already exist since it is imported to the table using X++, however, when creating a new position the ax still want to generate the position id `00001` which is already used

Comment: I don't have the code right now, I can post it by tomorrow, thanks

Comment: Why do you think changing the `nextval` value in table `SYSTEMSEQUENCES` (which controls the values of field `RecId`) would help with resolving an index violation issue with field `Position`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to change `nextval` in the `SYSTEMSEQUENCES` table - it has a different purpose. Instead, try the following:

- Open `Human resources > Setup > Parameters > Human resources shared parameters > Number sequences`.
- Right-click the `Position` number sequence code, select `View details`.
- Expand the `General` tab page, modify the `Next` number to be released from the number sequence.
- Click the `Status list` button in the action pane to make sure it doesn't contain numbers that have already been used.